# Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/my_package/cache/share_video_1610748162883.mp4

Tags: android

I want to share my video in WhatsApp. Video contain in URL where we have hosted. When user click on WhatsApp icon video should send to user from URL.
I have tried many thing but unable to succeed. I don't know why this giving me this Exception. what I'm doing wrong.

This is my Java code

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<String, String, Uri> {

    @Override
    protected Uri doInBackground(String[] fileURL) {
        Uri videoUri = null;
        String s = Arrays.toString(fileURL);
        String videoUrl = s.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
        try {
            File rootFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "share_video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
            URL url = new URL(videoUrl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(rootFile);
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", rootFile);
            f.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error....", e.toString());
        }
        return videoUri; // returns the file path to the video from storage

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Uri videoUri) {
        super.onPostExecute(videoUri);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("*/*");
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, videoUri);   //to share video
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Mainfest File

```
       <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="studio.pepup.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>

        </provider>
```

file_xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />

</paths>
```

Comment: About which exception are you talking?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in `getCacheDir()`. This means you need to replace:

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="." />
```

with:

```
<cache-path name="external_files" path="." />
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider?hl=en#SpecifyFiles) for more.